# Laravel save () retorna true mas não muda nada no banco de dados

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando fazer um UPDATE para trocar a senha do meu usuario, a função esta me retornando SUCESSO, mas quando vou no banco de dados não mudou nada.
Estou fazendo um post via postman, pra seguinte rota "http://localhost:8000/api/emitente/3", no meu body estou mandando a senha atual e a senha nova via x.www.form.urlencoded. Quando faço a validação se a senha atual é diferente da digitada ele me retorna 'Senhas não conferem' até ai tudo OK, mas quando é para mudar a senha atraves do save() ele não altera no banco.

my route

```
Route::post("emitente/{emit}", "EmitsController@alteraSenha");
```

my model

```
  namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Emit extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'emit';
    protected $fillable = ['senhaUsu'];    
    
}
```

my controller

```
 public function alteraSenha(request $request , Emit $emit){
    
    if(($emit->senhaUsu == $request->input('atual')) AND (!empty($request->input('nova')))){
        
        $emit->senhaUsu = $request->input('nova');
        
        if($emit->save()){ 

            return response()->json(['status'=>'sucesso']);
        }    
            
    }else{
        return response()->json(['status'=>'Senhas não conferem']);
    }  

}
```

Comment: inclui o retorno de `var_dump($emit)` (antes de `if($emit->save())`) na pergunta para que haja mais informação e assim possamos ajudar

Comment: coloquei var_dump($emit), ele me retorna 2 objetos, um com as mudanças que eu acabei de fazer no campo senhaUsu, e outro "original" com as informações vindas do banco.
object(App\Emit)#263 (26) {[
      "senhaUsu"
    ]=>
    string(4) "1233"
    [}  "original":protected
  ]=>[
      "senhaUsu"
    ]=>
    string(7) "dom1234"
    [

Comment: obs: estou usando laravel localhost, e meu banco esta online